# No visible @interface for 'SwiftController' declares the selector (from objective-c class)

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have an init method in Swift and I tried to call it from Objective-C class. But there is an error written "No visible @interface for 'NoteViewController' declares the selector 'initWithModel:withKeyboardType:'"

I add "target-Swift.h" and it's 100% correct because I already put it on another class and its works well. I've put `@objc` and make the init method modifier become `public`

this is the import

```
#import "gp27appj-Swift.h"
```

this is the init method

```
 @objc public init(model: NoteViewModel, with keyboardType: tagKeyboardType) {
        super.init(model: model)
        self.keyboardType = keyboardType
    }
```

this is how I called from objective-c

```
 viewController = [[NoteViewController alloc] initWithModel:noteViewModel withKeyboardType:(tagKeyboardType)gameContext.selectedAnswerType];
```

I expect everything works well because I already put everything in the right place. Thank you

---------- SOLVED thanks to @rmaddy

it's a silly mistake because the completion doesn't show up before

instead of

```
 viewController = [[NoteViewController alloc] initWithModel:noteViewModel withKeyboardType:(tagKeyboardType)gameContext.selectedAnswerType];
```

I should use

```
viewController = [[NoteViewController alloc] initWithModel:noteViewModel with:(tagKeyboardType)gameContext.selectedAnswerType];
```

Comment: Did you try to let Xcode do code completion as you type `[[NoteViewController alloc] init` ? What does it show?

Comment: @rmaddy dude, omg. thanks a lot. Now it works. instead, of "withKeyboardType" it's should be "with". Silly mistake !

Comment: Glad you solved it but instead of editing your question, you should post an actual answer below.